# Get facebook group size

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-group

I'm trying to get all the facebook groups of a user, and sort them according to various criteria. I can easily sort them by "facebook order" using this:

```
FB.api('/me/groups', {fields: 'id, name, bookmark_order'}, function(respGroups) {
  ...
});
```

However, I couldn't find an equivalent way to get each group size (number of members) without  inquiring facebook on each group's members separately...

Answer (score 0):

There's no field as `count` in the concerned APIs, but you can count the array size of your group members with a single call itself-

```
FB.api('/me/groups', {fields: 'id, name, bookmark_order, members'}, function(respGroups) {
    for(var i=0; i<respGroups.data.length; i++){
       var group_size = respGroups.data[i].members.data.length;
    }
});
```

Am afraid there's no other way you can get the number of group members without querying for the `members`!